# Phone is automatically restarting every 10-15 mins

Tags: 8.0, lumia

I bought Nokia Lumia 520, Windows 8 OS phone on May 24th. Within a week, i got an issue. If i keep my phone idle for some 10 minutes, i can't unlock the screen. I need to do a force restart by removing battery. If i won't do force restart, phone itself restarting randomly. I have done a factory reset as well, but it didn't resolve my problem. I given it to Nokia care for service, once they updated the software, next time they sent my mobile to the factory to find and fix the issue. When i got mobile back, the issue starts again within a day.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue in other Windows 8 OS Phones like HTC or Nokia?

Comment: I never saw I case like that. Even with WP7. Very uncommon.

Comment: No.  Your phone is a lemon.  Get a replacement.

Comment: Have you tried resetting as mentioned here? http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/reset-my-phone

Comment: @karancan Yes, i referred the site which you mentioned while doing factory reset.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you ever get warnings that the SIM card is not inserted? Trying to figure out if this is a similar issue to the one I had.

Comment: @Katana314 No. i m not getting any warnings. If i lock the screen, after sometimes, the phone become sleep mode[can't unlock]. We need to do force restart or remove battery. If i keep it in sleep mode, after few minutes[say 2 or 5] phone getting restarted by itself.

Comment: Good news. I got new phone as replacement. Now phone is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like something is very wrong with your phone. Please, have it replaced with a new one. Then your issue should be resolved.

Comment: I got new phone as replacement. Now phone is working fine.

Comment: @Sundar, maybe you should mark this answer as the correct one?